# Can I assign/copy a PHP MySQL Resource Variable to Other?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, resources

I've a Question. Can I assign a PHP MySQL Resource Variable to Other?

For Eg.

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sometable",$dbconn) or die("Wheewww!"); //$query, Resource variable

while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
 {
   echo $result['somefield']." ";
 }

$query_new=$query;  //Assigning mysql resource variable to other

while($result_new=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_new))
 {
   echo $result_new['somefield']." ";
 }
```

Whether the above code is right in all way? Please Share Your Thoughts.

Cheers,
JENSon.

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated, use PDO or mysqli instead. Have you tried that and did it work? Did you get any errors?

Comment: why do you want to so? when you can use the $query variable again.

Comment: @JensonMJohn : +1 for your question :D

Comment: prasanth-bendra :) @kingkero Yeah. Thanks. I'll be switching to PDO soon. To improve my knowledge & also to help others, I've posted some basics of PDO in my Blog (http://jenson.in/iblog/?p=86) osscube-solution I was trying to copy files from one DB to other. I'll have to loop through the same resource more than once, So planned for assigning the resource variable to other. But solution from deceze I think I should use mysql_data_seek function for getting my actual output..Cheers..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that just fine, but it won't do you any good. You have already iterated the result set, assigning the resource to another variable won't reset it. You have to reset the cursor in the result set using `mysql_data_seek`.

You should also stop using a *deprecated* API for MySQL and move to PDO or Mysqli.

Answer (score 3):

This should be no problem, you are simply pointing two variables to the same resource. However before you can loop through $query_new you will have to reset the internal data pointer using mysql_data_seek (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

Edit: deceze answer includes good advice on using non deprecated code